# c# scroll bar for a panel? for bunch of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, panel

More of an info question,  i have a panel on the left of my form that contains label, textboxs combos etc etc, but i need to create even more on the same page (not a sepereate form etc)there is basically no space left.  So im thinking of adding a scroll bar to the panel(if possible) this will enable the user to scroll up and down looking at the data break down of a multi series graph.
So in short do i:

- Create a panel and attach a scroll bar control(if such a thing exists)?
- Create a new control that already has an in-built scroll bar?
- non of these ideas, something better or easier?

This is a design question more than anything.... and i will admit....im terrible at design, and im pretty new to winforms and all of its controls.

heres a pic!

[image]

Any input would be great!
Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why don't you try to use a tab control?

Comment: forgot to mention the panel is in a tab control already

Comment: I suggest you to make form size more bigger as need to put control on it. Otherwise create a new tab and place required controls in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoScroll property can do this for you.  Just set it to True on the panel.  Then place the controls so that they extend beyond the edge of the panel, and a scroll bar will appear.

It might be easier to layout the controls first while the panel is bigger, then shrink the panel afterward when they're all in the correct positions.

Comment: If the controls are going to be repeatedly exactly, you may want to just create a UserControl.  It really depends on how you intend to use them.

Comment: For example, if each group of controls represents a class or a database object, then you could create a UserControl with all the text/label controls and give the UserControl a public property to allow you to set the associated class so each will auto fill its own data.  Then you can programmatically create as many of these controls as you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can solve your issue.
The first thing you could do is set your panel AutoScroll attribute to true
If you have different sections, tab control is definatly a good idea.

Comment: normally this would be the solution but as the pic shows its already in a form, and the users have requested the info break down on the same tab.......annoying as they are hehe.